# http response getting printed in browser if "Content-type" and "content-disposition" are set after writing in http "response" outputstream

Tags: java, http, servlets, http-headers

I have a use-case where I have to set "Content-type" and "content-disposition" after writing in http response outputstream instead of downloading as a file. Following sample code depicts the case :-

```
@Context
HttpServletResponse response;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String downloadFile() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("/var/tmp/input.txt");
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);

    copyStream(fs, response.getOutputStream());

    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + "ts.csv" + "\"");

    return "";
}
```

When I give a small input (input.txt file), my browser gives me option to download it but when the input is large, it prints the file content directly in the browser tab.

Any pointers what I can do such that it gives a file downoad option for large input as well?

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation at [*ServletResponse.setContentType*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29):

> *Sets the content type of the response being sent to the client, if the response has not been committed yet.*

And, as per documentation at [ServletResponse.getWriter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29):

> *Returns a PrintWriter object that can send character text to the client.*

In your coding, you are writing content to the `response` object before setting the `content-type`.

You should have not written into the response output stream, for your custom content type to work.

Change your code:

```
copyStream(fs, response.getOutputStream());

response.setContentType( "text/csv" );
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=\"" + "ts.csv" + "\"" );
```

To:

```
response.setContentType( "text/csv" );
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=\"" + "ts.csv" + "\"" );

copyStream(fs, response.getOutputStream());
```